# My sendmail.php isn't working. Doesn't send email

Tags: php

```
<?php 
$to = "jerrelldc@gmail.com";
$subject = "This is subject";
$message = "This is simple text message.";
$header = "From:".$_POST['from']." \r\n";
$retval = mail ($to,$subject,$message,$header);
if( $retval == true )  
{
    echo "Message sent successfully...";
}
else
{
    echo "Message could not be sent...";
}
?>
```

Why aren't emails sending? Am I missing something?

Comment: "enter code here" should be a comment?. Anyway, can you be more specific like, giving the error message or something like that?

Comment: When you run this code then what it returns?

Comment: check the mail in your spam folder.

Comment: Please check that your hosting provides mail service.

Comment: I haven't published the site yet. Maybe that's why?